# turning a two dimensional array into a two column dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

if I have the following, how do I make pd.DataFrame() turn this array into a dataframe with two columns. What's the most efficient way? My current approach involves creating copies out of each into a series and making dataframes out of them.

From this:

```
([[u'294 (24%) L', u'294 (26%) R'],
  [u'981 (71%) L', u'981 (82%) R'],])
```

to

```
x    y
294  294
981  981
```

rather than

```
x
[u'294 (24%) L', u'294 (26%) R']
```

my current approach. Looking for something more efficient

```
numL = pd.Series(numlist).map(lambda x: x[0])
    numR = pd.Series(numlist).map(lambda x: x[1])

    nL = pd.DataFrame(numL, columns=['left_num'])
    nR = pd.DataFrame(numR, columns=['right_num'])

    nLR = nL.join(nR)

    nLR
```

UPDATE**

I noticed that my error simply comes down to when you pd.DataFrame() a list versus a series. WHen you create a dataframe out of a list, it merges the items into the same column. Not so with a list. That solved my problem in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```py
data = [[u'294 (24%) L', u'294 (26%) R'],  [u'981 (71%) L', u'981 (82%) R'],]
    
clean_data = [[int(item.split()[0]) for item in row] for row in data]

# clean_data: [[294, 294], [981, 981]]
    
pd.DataFrame(clean_data, columns=list('xy'))

#         x    y
#    0  294  294
#    1  981  981
#
#    [2 rows x 2 columns]
```