# How to convert ndarray to pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have ndarray data with the shape of (231,31). now I want to convert this ndarray to pandas DataFrame with 31 columns. I am using this code:

```
for i in range (1,32):
      dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Column{}'.format(i):data[:,i-1]})
```

but this code just creates the last column, it means with 231 indexes and just 1 column, but I need 31 columns. is there any way to fix this problem and why it happens?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481954/turning-a-two-dimensional-array-into-a-two-column-dataframe-pandas

Comment: I also want to know why it happens. my question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you are creating a new dataframe, that is why only the last column remains.

You need to create the dataframe with `pd.DataFrame(data)`.

Comment: thank you, yes I just need to `dataset = pd.DataFrame(data)`, and it creates DataFrame with 231 indexes and 31 columns.